# SMPL preempt() in C

Tags: c

I've been recently given the SMPL library to model queue systems in C and some examples to try it out like the one below.

```
    #include "smpl.h"

    main()
      {
        real Ta=200.0,Ts=100.0,te=200000.0;
        int customer=1,event,server;
        smpl(0,"M/M/1 Queue");
        server=facility("server",1);
        schedule(1,0.0,customer);
        while (time()<te)
           {
             cause(&event,&customer);
             switch(event)
             {
                case 1:  /* arrival */
                   schedule(2,0.0,customer);
                   schedule(1,expntl(Ta),customer);
                   break;
                case 2:  /* request server */
                   if (request(server,customer,0)==0) then
                   schedule(3,expntl(Ts),customer);
                   break;
                case 3:  /* release server */
                   release(server,customer);
                   break;
             }
          }
          report();
     }
```

I am trying to modify this example a bit to use the function preempt() to manage priority and preemption within the queue. I made some changes to the code so now it looks like

```
    #include "smpl.h"

    main()
      {
        real Ta=200.0,Ts=100.0,te=200000.0;
        int customer,event,server;
        smpl(0,"M/M/1 Queue");
        server=facility("server",1);
        schedule(1,0.0,0);            //customer with priority 0
        schedule(1,0.0,1);            //customer with priority 1
        while (time()<te)
           {
             cause(&event,&customer);
             switch(event)
             {
                case 1:  /* arrival */
                   schedule(2,0.0,customer);
                   schedule(1,expntl(Ta),customer);
                   break;
                case 2:  /* request server */
                   if (preempt(server,customer,customer)==0) then     <--- change request for preempt()
                   schedule(3,expntl(Ts),customer);
                   break;
                case 3:  /* release server */
                   release(server,customer);
                   break;
             }
          }
          report();
     }
```

and when I run it it gives me the following error:

```
    **** Simulation Error at Time 12002.710
    Release of Idle/Unowned Facility
```

checking at the traces I find

```
                        --  token 0     -- SCHEDULE  EVENT 3
     time 11892.379     --  token 1     -- CAUSE  EVENT 1
                        --  token 1     -- SCHEDULE  EVENT 2
                        --  token 1     -- SCHEDULE  EVENT 1
                        --  token 1     -- CAUSE  EVENT 2
                        --  token 1     -- PREEMPT server:  INTERRUPT
                        --              --    SUSPEND  EVENT 1
                        --              --    QUEUE  token 0  (inq = 1)
                        --              --    RESERVE server for token 1
                        --  token 1     -- SCHEDULE  EVENT 3
     time 12002.710     --  token 0     -- CAUSE  EVENT 3
```

that is token 0 is trying to release the server, but the owner of the server is token 1 since it has preempted token 0 from the server at time 11892.379.

I don't know if the problem is due to some error in the library I've been given or if I'm doing something wrong with the preempt() function.

Anyone with some experience with this library that can enlighten me a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there has been no answer and I seem to have found out a way through I will post it for future reference.

SMPL preempt() function does not seem to handle well different tokens having the same id. A posible solution is then to dynamically change the token id at every new token arrival schedule operation.

```
    #include "smpl.h"

    main()
      {
        real Ta=400.0,Ts=100.0,te=200000.0;
        int customer,event,server,i;
        smpl(0,"M/M/1 Queue");
        trace(1);                   //debug
        server=facility("server",1);
        schedule(1,0.0,0);          //customer with priority 0
        schedule(1,0.0,1);          //customer with priority 1
        i=2;
        while (time()<te)
          {
            cause(&event,&customer);
            switch(event)
             {
                case 1:  /* arrival */
                   schedule(2,0.0,customer);
                   schedule(1,expntl(Ta),i); i++;
                   break;
               case 2:  /* request server */
                   if (preempt(server,customer,customer)==0) then
                   schedule(3,expntl(Ts),customer);
                   break;
               case 3:  /* release server */
                  release(server,customer);
                  break;
              }
          }
          report();
      }
```

In this example the priority for the preempt() call is equal to the token id, else it should have to be handled by hand but it does solve the main problem.